# Max6675 k thermocouple raspberry pi 3 using Nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, express, temperature

I'm working on a project using raspberry pi. I need to get **max6675 temperature reading using nodejs**. 
I can get values using python but after running for sometime

> Error: Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown): Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1157, in run

I'm using express framework and Python-shell npm. I execute .py file using setInterval() function.